# Exporting to Excel with the help of C# in Asp.net Web Forms gives me error "Invalid File extension"

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webforms, export-to-excel

I have the following code working to export the Excel file in my Desktop but when i run this code it runs perfectly but giving me error afterwards in Excel that It is INVALID FILE EXTENSION OR IT IS CORRUPTED, and ya when i open it ignoring the error there is still header with _DoPostBack method which says its unsafe to open this type of things.

Here is my code. If anyone could help me would be an appreciation.

```
rotected void dataExport(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//     Response.Clear();

//Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");


//Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

//System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

//System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
//new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

//datagrid.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

//Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

//Response.End();
    string filename = "MyFile.xls";
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    //Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename.ToString());
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        //To Export all pages
        datagrid.AllowPaging = false;
        datagrid.AllowSorting = false;

        datagrid.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
        foreach (TableCell cell in datagrid.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            cell.BackColor = datagrid.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in datagrid.Rows)
        {
            row.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = datagrid.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.BackColor = datagrid.RowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                cell.CssClass = "textmode";
            }
        }

        datagrid.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";

        Response.Write(style);

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());

        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    Response.Charset = "";
    this.EnableViewState = false;
    System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new   System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);
    datagrid.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
    Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
```

Comment: It's because you're not creating a legitimate Excel file. You're exporting HTML and saving it with an Excel extension. Don't do that. Use a library such as [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (my favorite), or [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) to generate a real Excel file.

Comment: No, because I'm not going to do your work for you and they have perfectly good examples on the sites I linked ot.